# Django Count ForeignKey to ForeignKey data on CBV ListView

Tags: django, django-models

I don't have an idea what title should be on this question.

but here the case.

I have CBV (ListView) that list the data. But I need add other data from other model also.

here my `models.py`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Periode(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class EmployeeSalary(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='employee')
    periode = models.ForeignKey(Periode, related_name='periode')
```

here what I need on my template.html:

```
#table
+-----------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| Periode   |Total Employee  | Salary Data   | Employee Not Have Data  |
+-----------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| January   | 100            | 50            | 50                      |
| February  | 100            | 70            | 30                      |
+-----------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

this is what I do now.

`views.py`

```
class PeriodeListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'periodes'
    model = models.Periode
```

`template_list.html`

```
{% for periode in periodes %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ periode.end_date.month }}</td>
  <td>{{ periode.periode.employee.count }}</td>
  <td>{{ periode.periode.count }}</td>
  <td>{{  }}</td>
</tr>

  {% endfor %}
```

periode & salary data work as well. but Total Employee & Employee Not have data I don't have an idea how to get it. trying with `periode.periode.employee.count` but din't work.

Comment: from `periode` instance, you can access `employee` via the related_name `employee` (You can have the total of EmployeeSalary)..  and there, `employee` is a FK to `Employee` model, how will you get the total of `employee` from it

Comment: yea, I don't know how to get employee count. should add `@properties` ?... or you have idea?... not use FK ways. Use like `total_employee = models.Employee.objects.count()` ?